# invalid command name "2001:172:16:21::36"

Tags: tcl

I need to assign my final variable with the following string UDP6:[2001:172:16:21::36]

```
  set ipAddr1 "UDP6,2001:172:16:21::36"
  set ipAddrArr [split $ipAddr1 ","]
  set ipAddrArr11 [lindex $ipAddrArr 0]
  set ipAddrArr12 [lindex $ipAddrArr 1]
  set tmp ":\["
  set ipAddr1Part [join "$ipAddrArr11 $ipAddrArr12" $tmp]
  set tmp1 "]"
  set ipAddrFinal [join "$ipAddr1Part$tmp1"]
```

When I run the tcl script, it gives invalid command name  as 2001:172:16:21::36.
I have printed ipAddrFinal value , it gives the expected one UDP6:[2001:172:16:21::36]

pls help me out? what am I missing

Comment: What are you not showing us? [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: The code fragment shown is fine.  Most likely you are using $ipAddrFinal in another context where the brackets get evaluated.   Check the error output to determine which line is causing the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The script as you have written it works fine; it assigns the string `UDP6:[2001:172:16:21::36]` to the variable `ipAddrFinal`. However, since it contains characters that are Tcl metacharacters in some contexts, I suspect that you are *then* using the string in an unsafe way, most likely with `eval` or possibly with `subst` or `uplevel`. If you look at the stack trace of the error (in the `errorInfo` global variable by default) you should be told pretty exactly where the offending code is; it might give a few places you need to look, but it usually isn't too hard to hunt down where the problem originates from.

If your problem comes from `uplevel`, you are probably going to need to use `list` to construct a command; 99.99% of all problems with `uplevel` are handled that way. If your problems come from `eval`, the chance's good that you need to switch to using expansion syntax. If your problems come from `subst` or are otherwise still deeply confusing, check back with us (*with your stack trace* if you are not sure where the problem is coming from).

---

### Example of a fix for `eval`:

Change:

```
set action "puts \"IP\\ address\\ is\\ $ipAddrFinal\""
eval $action
```

to:

```
set action [list puts "IP address is $ipAddrFinal"]
{*}$action
```

NB: The error from doing the `eval` is a reasonable example too:

```
invalid command name "2001:172:16:21::36"
    while executing
"2001:172:16:21::36"
    ("eval" body line 1)
    invoked from within
"eval $action"
```

Note that it says that it's in an `eval`, and that points squarely to unsafe script construction. The `list` command does *safe* script construction as one of its bonus superpowers.

Comment: Thanks i could find that it throws error when it evaluates subst part.So possibly it takes that square braces as command.How to deal with this.below is my part of code.. set commandList "snmpget  $snmpOptions -c $in_community $in_ipAddrFinal docsIfDocsisBaseCapability.0"

Comment: set errorStatus [eval "catch \{exec [subst $commandList] \} capabilityResult"].This is the code part where it handles error status